# Reflected XSS but no Content-Type is specified

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I have found parameter that simply reflects into response body, but no `Content-Type` is specified by server. It doesn't use any XSS-protection mechanisms like CSP or `X-XSS-Protection`. However, I was not able to fire payload in up-to-date Chromium or Firefox. Under what conditions can the payload be executed?
[image: example response]

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show what is exactly going, so it is not clear what exactly is happening in your case. But in general, if you want to have Cross Site **Scripting** you need a context which will execute this script. It does not help if the content is reflected inside plain text, CSV or similar - it needs to be something like HTML. The Content-Type is relevant in defining this document context. But even with HTML not everywhere script gets executed, so it needs to be in the relevant context there too.

Comment: @steffen I updated my post with an example screenshot and tried to inject `<html>` tag between `script`, but I had no luck.

Comment: What you're looking for is a MIME sniffing attack. Current browsers are a lot more careful interpreting content without a media type as `text/html`, exactly because the risk of an XSS attack. If you had the ability to inject content at the beginning of the response body, the attack would be easier. For example, see the [MIME sniffing rules from the corresponding WHATWG specification](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#identifying-a-resource-with-an-unknown-mime-type) (which Chrome and Firefox at least partially follow). If I find a solution for a substring injection, I'll write an answer.